# Inserting $1 in a snippet with snipMate

Tags: vim, snipmate

How can I insert a literal `$1` in a snippet, using snipMate? I could not find that information in the manual…

---

Results in nothing (tries to find a placeholder):

```
snippet s
    $1
```

Result in `$` only:

```
snippet s
    $$1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a workaround.  Use `$${0:1}`.  SnipMate doesn't interpret ${0}, but seems to insert the default text instead.

Comment: Ah! Thanks a lot Mr. Peterson. Very clever.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can't. The closest workaround is using default text:

```
snippet s
    $${1:1}
```

This requires you to hit tab once.

This is a listed issue with snipMate -- and has been for two years, so I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for it to get fixed.

Comment: I hope you will forgive me, but I decided to change the correct mark to @Adam H. Peterson who found a solution months after this question was posted. I though you'd be interested in knowing it also; for me it's specially essential in makefiles.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently on a promoting tour for [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715) on StackOverflow. UltiSnips support escaping chars, the corresponding snippet looks like this:

```
snippet s
\$1
endsnippet
```

A conversion script for snipMate snippets is shipped with UltiSnips, so switching is easy.